# Why is assigning to $bool1 or $bool2 different from assigining to the same statement wrapped in parenthesis?

Tags: php

I'm completely confused.  Why, on a grammatical level, would the two statements below be any different?

```
$bool1=false;
$bool2=true;

//Statement1
$result=$bool1 or $bool2;  // Returns false

//Statement2
$result=($bool1 or $bool2);  // Returns true
```

As far as I'm aware, those two statements should be completely and absolutely identical.  But, for some reason, they aren't.  I can work around this, but the fact that they aren't identical means I'm missing some aspect of the language, and I don't have a clue where to check.

Answer (score 3):

It's due to precedence rules. `or` has lower precedence than `=`, so Statement1 is parsed as:

```
($result = $bool1) or $bool2;
```

To get what you want, use `||` instead:

```
$result = $bool1 || $bool2;
```

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator (`=`) has higher precedence than the or operator (`or`)

```
$result=$bool1 or $bool2;
```

executes the assignment of $bool1 to $result first (giving FALSE) then the or with $bool2, which results in FALSE

```
$result=($bool1 or $bool2);
```

the brackets force `$bool1 or $bool2` to be executed first, which is a TRUE; and then that value is assigned to $result

Just to show the difference, try

```
$result=$bool1 || $bool2;
```

and

```
$result=($bool1 || $bool2);
```

because the or operator (`||`) has a higher precedence than the assignment operator (`=`)

This is one of those cases where the difference between `||` and `or` is significant

Comment: And here I was thinking 'or' and || were the same thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The statements are actually identical and evaluate the same thing, that is to say that if you print the entire line (including the assignment portion

```
$bool1=false;
$bool2=true;

//Statement1
var_dump($result=$bool1 or $bool2);  // Returns true

//Statement2
var_dump($result=($bool1 or $bool2));  // Returns true
```

The difference is in the assignment. In statement 1, it's read as `($result = $bool1) or $bool2` whereas statement 2 is read as `$result = ($bool1 or $bool2)`

Since bool1 is false and bool1 is true, in statement1, you end up with `$result or $bool2` which evaluates to `true` (but note that (`$result` is still false)

In statement 2, you end up with just `$result` (and `$result` is true).